# Ubuntu14.04 shortcut keys of external keyboard don't work

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

In Ubuntu 14.04 the keyboard shortcuts such as Ctrl+C of my laptop's external keyboard do not work, but they can be used in Windows. How to make the keyboard shortcuts available in my Ubuntu?

All shortcuts run well on my laptop's keyboard, but they can't be used on the external keyboard. Is there anything wrong about the I/O drivers or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about commands from the terminal?

If that is the case you can use `Shift` + `Ctrl` + `C` to copy.

Also, check the keyboard settings to make sure they weren't changed by accident. **System Settings -> Keyboard**.

Comment: All shortcuts run well on my lap-top's keyboard but they can't be used on the external keyboard.Is there anything wrong about I/O drivers or something else?